# "Extension not found or permission denied" after upgrading Umbraco from 4.11.1 to 6.2.1

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

From a .cshtml view I make an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: '/base/MemberService/Login',
 dataType: 'JSON',
 cache: false,
```

This logic placed in a separate class. `MemberService` is the class and `Login` is a method inside this class.

I am getting the error `<error>Extension not found or permission denied</error>` when calling the `/base/MemberService/Login` URL.

Error showing in Fiddler:
[image: Error showing in fiddle]

Upgrading Umbraco from version 4.9.0 to 4.11.1 did not cause any issues, but this issue occurred when trying to upgrade to 6.2.1.

Comment: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/cultiv-restcontour/requests-and-questions/15545-Extension-not-found-or-permission-denied, https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/2813-Extension-not-found-or-permission-denied-Error

Comment: The above link discuss about the issue in version 4. My application work fine in 4.11.1. Is umbraco 6 version compatible with /base/  syntax?

Answer (score 0):

in Your Web.config.
In < httpModules>:

```
<add name=" UmbracoModule" type="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule,umbraco" /> 
<add name="viewstateMoverModule" type="umbraco.presentation.viewstateMoverModule" /> 
<add name="umbracoBaseRequestModule" type="umbraco.presentation.umbracobase.requestModule" />
```

Replace those three with:

```
<add name="UmbracoModule" type="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule,umbraco" />
```

And in < modules> remove:

```
<add name=" UmbracoModule" type="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule,umbraco" /> 
<add name="viewstateMoverModule" type="umbraco.presentation.viewstateMoverModule" /> 
<add name="umbracoBaseRequestModule" type="umbraco.presentation.umbracobase.requestModule" />
```

Replace with:

```
<add name="UmbracoModule" type="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule,umbraco" />
```